# SlideMenuController is not being shown

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use `SlideMenuController` [library](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) to put a left menu on `Home` screen but after passing a `Login` screen. The problem is that when I click on the button of the `Login` screen, a blank screen is being shown without the menu.

What I have done:

- On `main.storyboard` I have added an `UIViewController` that has a button (that will be my future `Login` screen) and I have declared it as "Is Initial View Controller". I also have referenced this screen with `UIViewControllerProve`.

On `UIViewControllerProve` I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class UIViewControllerProve: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btnProve(sender: AnyObject) {
        createMenuView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    class ContainerViewController: SlideMenuController {

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") {
                self.mainViewController = controller
            }
            if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Left") {
                self.leftViewController = controller
            }
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

    }

    private func createMenuView() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController
        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hex: "689F38")
        leftViewController.mainViewController = nvc
        self.slideMenuController()?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        appDelegate!.window?!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
        appDelegate!.window?!.rootViewController = self.slideMenuController()
        appDelegate!.window?!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.slideMenuController()?.openLeft()
    }
}
```

- On `AppDelegate.swift` I have commented those functions: `createMenuView` and `application`.
- I am taking as reference the example that the creator has in his [GitHub](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift/releases).

How can I make that the menu will be shown when I click on the button of my `Login` screen? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you set slideviewcontroller to window rootviewcontroller only slideviewcontroller visble

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala Please, can you explain it a bit more expanded? I do not understand you at all.

Comment: when you set windows root view controller  , what ever the controller you set only that controller visible on window.

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala so what can I do to show both the controller and the menu?

Comment: set navigation controller to windows rootviewcontroller . on navigation controller do your animations

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala but I already have: `let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)`.

Comment: appDelegate!.window?!.rootViewController = nvc

Answer (score 0):

First Add This Line Appdelegate

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

     let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController

let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController


    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
     leftViewController.welcomescreen = nvc
    let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
     slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    slideMenuController.delegate = mainViewController2
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Then After You Add On Button Action
Only One Line

```
 slideMenuController()?.toggleLeft()
```

then open the slide menu and select the option .